# Targetting a UIButton in a UIView, with addTarget

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uikit

My ViewController.m creates an instance of a myUIView.
In myUIView a UIButton is created.

All seems good, except to capture the button presses I use **addTarget**, at the ViewController level.
Pressing the button causes a crash, saying: **"unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6c254e0..."**

Is this addTarget code wrong? Would appreciate anyone's assistance.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

<UIVIew implementation etc...>

[myUIView.myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myButtonIsPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}


- (void)myButtonIsPressed{
    NSLog(@"Pressed!");
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply remove : after myButtonIsPressed in the line :

```
[myUIView.myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myButtonIsPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: Thanks Sarah! :) I wish I had asked that 3 hours ago. I could have done something useful this morning!

Comment: I know :) Its a silly mistake I have done so many times and have wasted my time too..!

Comment: (Was waiting for it to let me.) Thanks

Comment: Some more information, both for Custom and for anyone else who comes across this post: the reason the : was incorrect is because it signifies that you're going to pass a variable to the myButtonIsPressed method.  Since myButtonIsPressed does not accept any arguments, you were thrown an error; myButtonIsPressed and myButtonIsPressed:(dataType)var are two completely different methods. Hope that helps!